# How to calculate approximate fourier coefficients using np.trapz

Tags: numpy, fft, numerical-methods

I have a dataset which looks roughly as follows (and is sinusoidal in nature):

```
TW-240-run1.txt

Point Number     Temperature 
0    51.504781 
 1   51.487722 
 2   51.487722 
 3   51.828893 
 4   51.828893 
 5   51.436547 
 6   51.368312 
 7   51.726542 
 8   51.368312 
 9   51.317137 
 10      51.317137 
 11      51.283020 
 12      51.590073 
.
.
.
9599     51.675366
```

[image: plot of imported data]

I am tasked with finding the fundamental/first fourier coefficients, a_n and b_n for this dataset, by means of a numerical integration technique. In this case, I am simply using numpy.trapz from numpy, which aims to implement the trapezium rule. The fourier coefficients, a_n and b_n can be calculated with the following formulae:

[image: fourier coefficient formulae]

where tau () is the time period of the sine function. For my case,  = 240 seconds (referring to the point number 240 on the data sheet), and thus the bounds of integration are 0 to 240. T(t) from the above formulae is the data set and n = 1.

My current code for trying to calculate the fourier coefficients is as follows:

```
# Packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
 
#input data from datasheet, the loadtxt below takes in the data from t = 0s to t = 240s
x1, y1 = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\y2python\y2python\thermal_4min_a.txt', unpack=True, skiprows=3)



tau_4min = 240.0


def cosine(period, t, n):
    return np.cos((2*np.pi*n*t)/(period)) #defines the cos term for the a_n formula

def sine(period, t, n): #defines the sin term for the a_n formula
    return np.sin((2*np.pi*n*t)/(period))

a_1_4min = (2/tau_4min)*np.trapz((y1*cos_term_4min), x1) #implement a_n formula (trapezium rule for T(t)*cos)
print('a_1 is', a_1_4min)

b_1_4min = (2/tau_4min)*np.trapz((y1*sin_term_4min), x1) #implement b_n formula (trapezium rule for T(t)*cos)
print('b_1 is', b_1_4min)
```

Essentially what this is doing is, it takes in the data, but only up to the row index 241 (point number 240), and then multiplies it by the sine/cosine term from each of the above formulae. However, I realise this isn't calculating the fourier coefficients properly.

My question(s) are as follows:

**Will my code work if I can find a way to set limits of integration for np.trapz and then importing the entire data set, instead of only importing the data points from 0 to 240 and multiplying it by the cos or sine term, then using np trapz on that product, as I am currently doing (0 and 240 are supposed to be my limits of integration)**

Comment: You should use at least a full period, which appears to be closer to 2400 in the plot. Using period 240 will not allow you to get a useful reproduction of the data curve by a sine curve. You can find the exact value of the period by searching for the second point that the first value is crossed again. What exactly is the obstacle that you wish to overcome?

Comment: I made a very basic error, I misread the units of the dataset, and so the whole period is 2400 not 240. Thanks for helping me spot that, it was a late night.